# Using Does Not Equal in Search Filters

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, soundcloud

I am putting together a script that needs to search sounds on Soundcloud and use multiple comparisons in the search parameters.

For example, maybe I want all the results from a "Harry Connick Jr." query that are NOT tagged as "Rock and Roll".

```
tracks = client.get('/tracks', q='Harry Connick Jr', tags!='Rock and Roll')
```

That does not work, and just returns...

```
non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Is there a way to include these conditions in my search query? Or is my only option to get the full set of results and then scrub the data on my side?

Comment: What's the type of `client`? how did you create that object?

Comment: client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='my987client654id321',
                           client_secret='my123client456secret789',
                           username='myusername',
                           password='mypassword')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for keyword arguments is `=`. So here

```
client.get('/tracks', q='Harry Connick Jr', tags!='Rock and Roll')
```

`q='Harry Connick Jr'` is a keyword argument. However

`tags!='Rock and Roll'` is a boolean expression which evaluates to `True`/`False`

If there is a way to pass the NOT version, it will probably look like a function that wraps the string. You could try adding a link to the relevant docs in your question

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it, and from what I'm reading here the query functionality is very limited.. so I don't imagine it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get all results from the API and then filter them on your side.